# Зачем нужен второстепенный ключ GPG

Tags: linux, gpg

Создал *RSA+RSA* ключик.

при выводе `gpg --list-keys` получаю строки:

```
pub номер ключа (публичный)
uid контактная инфа
sub другой номер ключа (второстепенный)
```

Подскажите, зачем нужен второстепенный ключ?

Answer (score 1):

Эти ключи используются для подписи или шифрования. Их особенность, что они привязаны к главной паре ключей (см. pub).

https://wiki.debian.org/subkeysOpenPGP further supports subkeys, which are like the normal keys, except they're bound to a master key pair. A subkey can be used for signing or for encryption. The really useful part of subkeys is that they can be revoked independently of the master keys, and also stored separately from them.